# Lower case to upper case

Tags: c, character, bit-manipulation

How to convert lower case ASCII char into upper case using a bitmask (no -32 allowed)?

I'm not asking for solving my homework, only some hints.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you state "(no -32 allowed)", I guess you know that the difference between lower case characters and upper case characters is 32. Now convert 32 to its binary representation, there's only one bit set. After that, work out a way to use a [bit mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) to switch the bit.

Comment: Indeed, though of course people did give away the direct answer below ;o. I believe it should be noted, for any readers, that the OP did indicate ASCII characters. Thus, this method, or any presented on this page, would not be necessarily always be valid for non-English Unicode (16-bit/wide-char) characters. I just wanted to make this clarification. It would work for English, but dunno about other languages. Therefore, be careful, and remember not all humans speak English and our Universal Translator has yet to be invented ;p. The CRT toupper and tolower functions should be used for chars.

Answer (score 4):

Think about the differential between lower and upper case (0x20) and then apply the appropriate mask to your value

XOR to get lower from upper or upper from lower

Comment: Or just use XOR for both of them ;)

Comment: Once again, if you're going to run around willy-nilly down voting answers, please explain why.

Answer (score 3):

For actual code, you should be library functions, such as toupper() or towupper(), or something able to handle the complexity of Unicode.

Comment: +1 to compensate the one who is running around wildly here and votes down correct answers.

Comment: @9090 So many practical problems *are* limited to ASCII. Waving your cane and saying something akin to "you damn kids will put someone's eye out with that ASCII" isn't really useful.

Answer (score 2):

Just translate `+-32` into a bit operation. `32` can be written as `2^x`.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the hexadecimal values of lower case ASCII characters to upper case ASCII characters and the solution should become clear.  It may also be helpful to compare the binary values if the solution is not evident right away.

Answer (score 0):

The operation of subtracting a 32 from ASCII code of a small Latin letter flips the 5th bit from 1 to 0.

Comment: no it doesn't, it only affects one bit : 32 = 0x20 = 00100000

Comment: You're right, within the set of small Latin letters the 5th bit is always one. sorry, got carried away by international language experience. It's even more straightforward then.

Answer (score 0):

As you specify this, your homework is not well defined. The C standard knows nothing about a particular encoding of the source or execution character set, in particular it doesn't assume anything that comes close to ASCII or so.

So wnoise was right, the **only** standard way to deal with these things are the predefined functions and macros that are provided for such an effect.

Comment: From the OP, "How to convert lower case ASCII char into upper case".  From 'man ascii' - "ASCII  is  the  American  Standard  Code  for  Information Interchange.  It is a 7-bit code." The OP doesn't want a standard way, the OP wants to convert ASCII characters from lower case to upper case using a bitmask.  In many cases this is an easy way to ease people into bitmasks as they can then see the exact effect that they have.

Comment: Agreed, given that he defined ASCII in the topic, he is excused ;)

Answer (score -1):

try and with 0xDF (hex) or 011011111 binary